# writing a ripple carry adder in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm attempting to write a ripple carry adder in verilog.

```
module half_adder(a,b,sum,carry);
   input a,b;
   output sum,carry;
   assign sum=a^b;
   assign carry=a&b;
endmodule


module full_adder(a,b,cin,sum,cout);
   input a,b,cin;
   output sum,cout;
   wire   t1,t2;
   half_adder h(a,b,t1,t2);
   assign cout=t1&cin;
   assign sum=t1^cin;
   assign cout=t2|cout;
endmodule // full_adder

module ripple_carry_adder(input1,input2,answer);
   input [31:0] input1,input2;
   output [31:0] answer;
   integer       carry,t;
   genvar        i;
   initial begin
     assign carry=1'b0;
   end

   for(i=0;i<=31;i=i+1)
     begin
        full_adder f(input1[i],input2[i],carry,answer[i],t);
        assign carry=t;
     end
endmodule
```

however when i compile using the iverilog simulator, the following error log shows up(repetitive errors removed) :

```
   ripple_carry_adder.v:28: warning: Couldn't build unique name for unnamed generate block - using internal name $gen1
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30: warning: Port 3 (cin) of full_adder expects 1 bits, got 32.
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30:        : Pruning (signed) 31 high bits of the expression.
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30: error: reg t; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30: error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30:      : Port cout of full_adder is connected to t
    ripple_carry_adder.v:31: error: reg carry; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
    ripple_carry_adder.v:28: warning: Couldn't build unique name for unnamed generate block - using internal name $gen1
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30: warning: Port 3 (cin) of full_adder expects 1 bits, got 32.
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30:        : Pruning (signed) 31 high bits of the expression.
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30: error: reg t; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30: error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
    ripple_carry_adder.v:30:      : Port cout of full_adder is connected to t
    ripple_carry_adder.v:31: error: reg carry; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
```

Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT:** Using the generate statement now.Still have doubt about the type of carry.

```
module ripple_carry_adder(input1,input2,answer);
   input [31:0] input1,input2;
   output [31:0] answer;
   wire          carry;
   wire          t;

   initial begin
     carry=1'b0;
   end
   genvar        i;
   generate for(i=0;i<=31;i=i+1)
     begin
        full_adder f(input1[i],input2[i],carry,answer[i],t);
        carry=t;
     end endgenerate
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get rid of the initial block. You can drop `t`. Then using an generate block:

```
   wire [31:0] carry;
   genvar i;
   full_adder f(input1[0],input2[0],1'b0,answer[0],carry[0]);
   generate // optional in IEEE std 1364-2005 and IEEE std 1800
   for(i=1;i<=31;i=i+1)
     begin
        full_adder f(input1[i],input2[i],carry[i-1],answer[i],carry[i]);
        //assign carry=t;
     end
   endgenerate
endmodule
```

Alternatively, something that worked with the old 1364-1995 style:

```
full_adder f[31:0](input1[31:0],input2[31:0],{carry[30:0],1'b0},answer[31:0],carry[31:0]);
```

Comment: Will the type of i remain genvar?

Comment: I'm getting this warning(i'm using the generate block):  warning: Couldn't build unique name for unnamed generate block - using internal name $gen1

Comment: Odd. Must be a limitation of your simulator. Warning should go a way if you apply a label to your `begin` statement inside the for-loop. Ex `begin : my_label`

Answer (score 0):

1. `assign` statements are not to be used inside of statement blocks. Anytime you have a `begin`/`end` block, the left-hand side of the statement gets set without using the `assign` keyword. e.g.:

   ```
   initial begin
        carry = 1'b0
   end
   ```
2. You cannot instantiate modules inside a procedural block or for-loop (e.g. `full_adder`), you need to use a generate statement instead. You declared a genvar, so I think you meant to do this, but you don't seem to have the generate statement.
3. You cannot drive a `reg/integer` type from the output of a module, `reg/integers` can only be driven from a procedural block. Change type `t` from an `integer` to a `wire[31:0]` instead.

Comment: So does that mean I cannot instantiate full_adder module from the loop? Does that mean that I have to create 32 separate instances of full_adder one-by-one?

Comment: You can make use loop, but your syntax is not correct. You need to look up and use the `generate`/`endgenerate` keywords. I would give an example but I don't typically use them, so I'm not sure I'd get the syntax right.

Comment: The `generate`/`endgenerate` keywords are optional since IEEE std 1364-2005, see section 12.4.1. The keywords are requited (and introduced) in 1364-2001. The error and warning messages suggests 1364-2005 compliance.